# Download anonymous OSM full history data (no User Id/ Nicknames)

Tags: openstreetmap, europe, osm-full-history

Here my Background:

I intend to use OSM Full History Data for OSM data quality analysis. This is part of my current thesis and the data will be stored on a companies computer (Germany). Since the new "General Data Protection Regulation" of the EU handling "potential personal data" legally is more difficult. OSM Contributor IDs and Nicknames are such data meaning in my case I can't store them legally on my computer. (Source i.a. FOSSGIS 2018, Zscheile, *Datenschutz und die Daten der zu OpenStreetMap Beitragenden*)

---

So my question: **How can I download OSM Full History Data (or Changesets) anonymized or without any User IDs or Nicknames?**

Downloading and deleting the IDs, Nicknames already violates the law as I see it. (Includes storing the data, even if for a short time.)

Kind regards

Comment: Only Geofabrik offers country extracts without meta data. This doesn't include Full History files, though. Planet files or full history dumps without meta data is still in discussion and not available yet.

Comment: There's also some follow up discussion here: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=706334#p706334  and a detailed description on how to generate such a Full history planet with reduced meta data 'on-the-fly' using osmium tool.